# Type '{ data: number; }' is not assignable to type '(obj: any) => any' error in typescripts

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have an object called `new Store`, it requires a parameter called `state` which accepts a list of states.

The issue I have is how to implement the interface of the state property,

This is the error I have

**Issue**

```sh
Type '{ data: number; }' is not assignable to type '(obj: any) => any'.
```

I would appreciate if someone can help me how to configure the interface that adapts to the property `state: {count: 1}`

**store.ts**

```js
const createStore = () => new Store({
  state:{
    count: 1
  },
})
```

**IStoreOptions.ts**

```js
export interface IStoreOptions<T> {
  state: (obj: T) => T
}
```

**Store.ts**

```js
export class Store{
  state: any;
 
  constructor(options: IStoreOptions<any>){
    if(options.state){
      let state = options.state;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the `Store` class and how does it use `IStoreOptions`?

Comment: @AlexWayne, I just added the Store class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IStoreOptions<T>` interface defines `state` as `(obj: T) => T`. This represents a **function** that accepts a generic type `T obj` argument and returns a generic  type `T`.

Try defining `IStoreOptions<T>` as

```
export interface IStoreOptions<T> {
  state: T
}
```

Note that given this solution if `T` is `any` then the implementing class of `IStoreOptions` can set `T` to any type as it wants. It does not have to define `state` as `any`.

Comment: Awesome, the function casting was pretty much the issue. My only concern with changing it to `object` is that it defeats the purpose of having the generic...depending on how you wanted to implement the 'list of states'.